# How to access variables declared in a function, from another function using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

In Javascript i need to access variables declared in a function from another function like:

```
function abc()
{
  var a = 'StackOverflow';
}
```

Outside that `function abc` i need to access `variable a`

I tried like:

```
var s = function abc()
{
    var a = 'StackOverflow';
} 

alert(s.a);
```

I can access value of `a` by declaring it as global variable but i want to know how to access it from reference of the `function abc`

Please solve this issue

Thank You.

Comment: You can't. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: A local variable lives on the stack and goes away and cannot be accessed once the function returns, unless you expose it through a closure, a global, or your return it from that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function abc()
{
    this.a = 'StackOverflow';
    this.b = 'jQuery Core';
    this.c = 'JavaScript';
} 

var s = new abc();

alert( s.a );
```

Alternatively, if you have no other operations use this notation:

```js
var s = {
   a: 'StackOverflow',
   b: 'jQuery Core',
   c: 'JavaScript'
}; 

alert( s.a );
```

Comment: What if i have an `variable` declared in `function abc` and a value is assigned to it in an `inner function` ...

Comment: Variables defined within functions are local to that function, unless the variables are defined as properties of the function as above.

Comment: Those aren't really variables in  your `abc` function. You should explain how what the OP is asking for is impossible, and how this achieves a similar goal. Also explain that you are creating globals if `abc()` is called without `new`

Answer (score 0):

That's called JavaScript objects! Use this way:

```
var s = new function abc()
{
    this.a = 'StackOverflow';
}
```

And call this way:

```
s.a; , e.g alert(s.a);
```

Or in other way:

```
var s = function abc()
{
    var a = 'StackOverflow';
    return {
        a: a
    };
}
```

And you can get it like:

```
s().a;
```

Comment: `s.a();`? `a` is not `function`

Answer (score 0):

You can take a function with own property:

```js
var s = function () {
    function abc(r) {           // declare function with one parameter as example
        return Math.PI * r * r; // do something, here return area of circle as example
    }
    abc.a = 'StackOverflow';    // set property a with value
    return abc;                 // return function with property
}();                            // IIFE
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = s.a + '<br>' + s(3);
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```